# Lift RewriteResponse not finding a valid url

Tags: scala, url-rewriting, lift

Hi I'm having some trouble with Lift and URL rewriting. I've written a simple rewrite rule:

```
LiftRules.rewrite.append {
  case RewriteRequest(
    ParsePath(List("user", userID), _, _, _), _, _) => {
        println(userID)
        RewriteResponse(List("viewUser"), Map("userID" -> urlDecode(userID)))
    }
}
```

So when I enter http://localhost:8080/user/brian I expect a call to be made to the viewUser.html file I have placed in the webroot directory.
The mark up of viewUser.html is very simple:

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
    <p>ViewUser</p>
</lift:surround>
```

But instead of seeing viewUser I get an error:

> The Requested URL /user/brian was not found on this server

Also if I enter the URL of viewUser by hand: http://localhost:8080/user/brian I get the same error.

I am out of ideas on this one, I did find a similar [error](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/7e35f37e06ba0cc8) which happens through the SiteMap system.

I've tried this with a cleanly checked out lift-archetype-blank project, by adding the viewUser.html and adding the single chunk of rewrite code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added "viewUser" to the site map.  Without doing so Lift doesn't know where to find page.

Comment: Excellent, works fine now. I'm working through the Exploring Lift book at the moment, I didn't see this explicitly mentioned in the Lift Fundamentals chapter? Ah well one way or another it works now ;)