# Lift URL path mapping?

Tags: scala, url-rewriting, lift

I am starting from the Maven chat example and would like to extend it so that multiple independent chats can happen at different URL paths.  For now I would be satisfied mapping multiple pages to the index.

My best guess is to put something like [Lift RewriteResponse not finding a valid url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219536/lift-rewriteresponse-not-finding-a-valid-url) in the boot strap class.  But so far nothing I have tried works.

I am a bit frustrated by the lack of well explained examples on how to do path mapping  for different common use cases (same goes for most lift documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html#toc-Subsection-3.2.7

This section describes how to use parameterized URLs.

If you want an example of multiple chat rooms, please download http://tunaforcats.com/ chat_done.tgz

Thanks!